# Iphone location to MySQL Database 

Tags: php, mysql, ios, post

I am trying to send a few values to a database.
Here's my code in iOS, and my Php code.

I am recieving the location in the background, and want to store this in my database,

Any help would be nice.
Thank you

```
NSString *latitude =  [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", newLocation.coordinate.latitude];
NSString *longitude =  [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", newLocation.coordinate.longitude];
NSString *stringFromDate = [formatter stringFromDate:newLocation.timestamp];


NSMutableURLRequest *request =
[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:
 [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.yourdomain.com/location.php"]];

[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

NSString *postString = [postString stringByAppendingFormat: latitude, longitude, stringFromDate];

[request setValue:[NSString
                   stringWithFormat:@"%d", [postString length]]
  forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-length"];

[request setHTTPBody:[postString
                      dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];




}

- (void) connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response{
NSHTTPURLResponse* httpResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse*)response;
   [httpResponse statusCode];
}
```

And my PHP File

```
  <?php
  // Connecting, selecting database

  $id = $POST['id'];
$longitude = $POST['longitude'];
  $latitude = $POST['latitude'];
 $timestamp = $POST['stringFromDate'];



  $link = mysql_connect('server', 'user', 'pass')
or die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());

 mysql_select_db('db_name') or die('Could not select database');

 // Performing SQL query
  $query = "INSERT INTO table locatie=(id, longitude, latitude, timestamp)VALUES ('NULL',   '".$longitude."', '".$latitude."', '".$timestamp."')";
 $result = mysql_query($query) or die('Query failed: ' . mysql_error());

  echo "OK";

 // Free resultset
 mysql_free_result($result);

 // Closing connection
 mysql_close($link);
 ?>
```

I get the EXC_BAD_ACCES on this line: **FIXED**

```
  NSString *postString = [postString stringByAppendingFormat: latitude, longitude, stringFromDate]; **FIXED**
```

Thank you verry much.

Greets

Answer (score 1):

The assignment of your post string variable happens after the right side is evaluated, so when you use the postString variable there, it's simply whatever garbage was on the stack and almost certainly not a pointer to a valid string. Simply create that string like you did your others:

```
// fix the formatting as necessary for your app
NSString* postString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@ %@", latitude, longitude, stringFromDate];
```

Comment: Thank you very Much. At least my app doesn't pauses anymore. I will now look at my Database to see if it stores the values. Thank you!

Comment: Oke i checked my database, but it doesn't give me any values in it.

Comment: @davidraijmakers did you reformat your post string correctly? The answer I gave fixes the EXC_BAD_ACCESS exception from your question title, but it's not a properly formatted query string. You need to add the variable assignments and such that your server is going to read.

Comment: i only changed your little piece of code.
I dont't really know what i'm doing wrong.

Comment: I changed also this: $query("INSERT INTO locatie (id, longitude, latitude, timestamp)
VALUES (NULL, $longitude,$latitude,$timestamp )");   

And your NSString* postString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@ %@", latitude, longitude, stringFromDate];